# How can I implement a moving standard deviation for a time series?

Tags: plotting, function-construction, time-series

I imported the following dataset and converted it into a time series.

```
dataSet = 
  Import["http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/AirPassengers.csv", "HeaderLines" -> 1 , "DateStringFormat" -> {"Year", "-", "Month"}]; 
ts = TimeSeries[dataSet];
```

Because I didn't find a built-in function function for a moving standard deviation, I implemented one with the following code.

```
A = Table[dataSet[[i ;; i + 11, 2]], {i, 1, Length[dataSet] - 11}];
B = TimeSeries[N[StandardDeviation @ Transpose[A]]];

Show[
  DateListPlot[ts, ImageSize -> Medium, PlotLegends -> {"Original"}], 
  ListLinePlot[MovingAverage[ts, 12], 
    PlotLegends -> {"Rolling Mean"}, PlotStyle -> {{Red, Dashing[Tiny]}}],
  ListLinePlot[B, 
    PlotLegends -> {"Rolling STD"}, PlotStyle -> {{Green, Dashing[Large]}}]]
```

[image]

Please feel free to comment about implementing a moving standard deviation for a time series.

**Updated**

Dear Alexey Golyshev, m_goldberg, Yves Klett, Mr.Wizard
Thanks for your reply.

1. I applied the function "MovingMap", it works with list or vector, however, it doesn't accept timeseries(ts) as an argument.

   MovingMap[StandardDeviation, ts, 12]
2. The "Moving STD" cannot be shown correctly; it is because I cannot find a function "MovingStandardDeviation" which is accepted the same arguments as MovingAverage.
3. Source of data has been updated."http://www.analyticsvidhya.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/AirPassengers.csv"

Comment: Since you don't give us data that allows to experiment with your code, alll I can do is give you some general advice: before trying to plot B, validate that it actually contains the numbers you want to plot.

Comment: What exactly is the question here?  Is this a request for a [code-review](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code-review)?  If so it should be tagged accordingly.  Questions of the form *“I use ______ for ______, what do you use?"* are specifically **off-topic.**  See:  [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: I think I misread your question.  So you do not have a working solution, and you do not have code that you wish to debug?  If this is the case then I suggest you rewrite the question removing things that are irrelevant, e.g. `MovingAverage`, and instead focus I a clear description of what you need.  Example data would be useful as well; for example is it uniformly sampled or irregular?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
ma = MovingMap[Mean, ts, Quantity[12, "Months"]];    
sd = MovingMap[StandardDeviation, ts, Quantity[12, "Months"]];

DateListPlot[
 {ts, ma, ma + sd , ma - sd}, 
 PlotLegends -> {"Original", "Moving Mean", "+ Moving STD", "- Moving STD"}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear Alexey Golyshev, Thank you.